# C# not choosing the right overload with a default value

Tags: c#

I am using the [FluentValidation framework](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) in C# which has the following two method overloads:

```
IRuleBuilder<TObject, TProperty>
    IRuleBuilderOptions<TObject, TProperty> Equal(TProperty toCompare, [IEqualityComparer comparer = null])
    IRuleBuilderOptions<TObject, TProperty> Equal(Expression<Func<TObject,TProperty>> expression, [IEqualityComparer comparer = null])
```

Basically one of the overloads lets you pass in an actual TProperty to compare, and the other lets you do a lambda that returns a TProperty from a TObject.

When I do the following it works:

```
RuleFor(r => r.First).Equals(r => r.Second);
```

It is getting the right overload in this case. When I try and pass in a value for the comparer it defaults to the other overload:

```
RuleFor(r => r.First).Equals(r => r.Second, new ObjectComparer()); // will not compile
```

This will not compile because it thinks I'm trying to use the first overload.

Is there a way I can force C# to use the second overload?

Edit:

ObjectComparer is an IEqualityComparer:

```
public class ObjectComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyClass>
{
     // ...
}
```

Comment: Maybe cast the 2nd param to whatever that method is expecting?

Comment: Is Comparer an IEqualityComparer? Based on your sample code, I assume it is but wanted to make sure.

Comment: Show the code for Comparer. I think like others pointed, it might not implements `IEqualityComparer`

Comment: Yes Comparer is an IEqualityComparer. I will update my code.

Comment: Oh I think I see. IEqualityComparer<T> does not implement IEqualityComparer?

Comment: It does not. Just checked it.

Comment: @Dismissile interfaces don't implement other interfaces; they inherit from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IEqualityComparer<T>` does not inherit `IEqualityComparer` and therefore your class does not implement `IEqualityComparer`! Implement both of them.

Comment: That was it. I guess I assumed too much.

Comment: The C# specification uses the term "inherits from" to describe the relationship between an interface and its base interfaces, if any.  "Implements" describes the relationship between a class or struct and an interface.

Comment: @phoog I think most people can infer what he was saying regardless.

Comment: @Dismissile of course, the meaning is clear, but the distinction is a useful one.

Comment: I changed the text in order to clarify it.

Comment: @phoog: Yes, it does, but I heartily wish it did not. Though technically this is inheritance, because members of the "base" interfaces are members of the "derived" interface, this does not match many people's intuition about what "inheritance" is. (For example, many people think of inheritance as primarily a *mechanism* for *sharing implementation details* but clearly interfaces have no implementation details.) I think of interfaces that "inherit from" other interfaces as rather being *contracts* that *require that you meet other contracts*.

Comment: @EricLippert what word would you use to describe the relationship?  "Implements" implies implementation details even more strongly than "inherits from" does!  Your point about contracts is very well taken, but I can't think of a concise way of expressing "requires implementers also to meet the contract of" :-S

Comment: "extends" would be a good term. VB uses the `Inherits` keyword.

Comment: @phoog: How about "requires"? I wish C# had chosen a slightly more verbose syntax here. When you say "class C : I" you do not know syntactically whether I is an interface or a base class. I would rather see something like "class C extends B implements I1, I2" and "interface I5 requires I3, I4".